# how to make fastapi use x-gitlab-token header for authentication

Tags: gitlab, webhooks, fastapi

I used this [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/) to secure some endpoints in my fastapi app.
It seemed to be working fine, and I was also able to run some tests (using pytest):

```
...
client = TestClient(app=app)
response = client.post(
            "/my_end_point",
            json={'data':'model'},
            headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"},
        )
...
```

My problem is, I want to connect my app to a Gitlab Webhook, and when doing that, Gitlab sends this header:

```
{'x-gitlab-token':'some-token-that-can-be-defined-when-setting-up-the-webhook'}
```

That means, even if I configure a valid token in the Gitlab Webhook configuration, it is not accepted by my FastAPI app, which returns **401 Not authorized** error.

I guess my question is how to instruct FastApi to take the token from 'x-gitlab-token' key and not from 'Authorization' key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an example of how you can [use `Header` in a dependency function in FastAPI's user guide](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/dependencies-in-path-operation-decorators/#add-dependencies-to-the-path-operation-decorator).

A self-contained example:

```
import uvicorn

from fastapi import (
    Depends,
    FastAPI,
    Header,
    HTTPException,
)

def authenticate_gitlab(x_gitlab_token: str = Header(...)):
    if x_gitlab_token != 'magic':
        raise HTTPException(status_code=403)

    return x_gitlab_token

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def req(authenticated_with: str = Depends(authenticate_gitlab)):
    return {'authenticated_with': authenticated_with}

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("foo:app", host="127.0.0.1", port=5000, log_level="info")
```

This accepts any request with `X-Gitlab-Token` set to `magic`, while refusing other keys:

```
λ curl http://localhost:5000 -H "X-GitLab-Token: foo"
{"detail":"Forbidden"}

λ curl http://localhost:5000 -H "X-GitLab-Token: magic"
{"authenticated_with":"magic"}
```

You can use the `dependencies` argument when creating an APIRouter to have the dependency run before every route in a given router (which you can composition together as you need from multiple routers):

```
authenticated_router = APIRouter(dependencies=[Depends(authenticate_gitlab)])
```

Comment: yes, I understand your answer. It works for gitlab webhooks, but it renders my other scenario obsolete, because I already had a **depend** statement on the endpoint, which ensured that the user was authenticated already with the user/password flow. (as described on the documentation link I have posted in the question).

Comment: The easiest way to solve that would be to keep the `/webhooks` authentication and the other authentication separate, and use two different APIRouter's with their own dependencies (one for the regular token authentication and one for the webhook authentication). If you need to have both ways of authentication for a single endpoint, you can use configure `OAuth2PasswordBearer` with `auto_error=False` to make it return None, and then wrap it in your own function to only error out if both is None instead - but you should still use two routers to limit the `authenticate_gitlab` function ..

Comment: .. to only be valid for the `/webhooks` endpoint. That would protect the rest of the application if the gitlab token suddenly leaks for some reason.